# "stringsMatchingRegularExpression" is deprecated in Swift 2, what should I use instead?

Tags: regex, swift2

This is the old function which is not working on Xcode 7 Beta 5:

```
func onlyDoubleUse(textField: AnyObject){
    let field = textField.object! as! UITextField
    let subStringArray: [String]?
    do {
        subStringArray = try field.text!.stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression: "[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{1,}")
    } catch _ {
        subStringArray = nil
    }
    if(subStringArray?[0] != nil){
        field.text = subStringArray![0]
    }else{
        field.text = ""
    }
}
```

Apple has removed `stringsMatchingRegularExpression` in Swift 2.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive method which gets added to `String` though an extension:

```
extension String {
    func stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression: String) -> [String] {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(expression, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) {
            return [self[range]] + self[range.endIndex..<self.endIndex].stringsMatchingRegularExpression(expression)
        }
        return []
    }

    // if you have a large string you should use this method
    func stringsMatchingRegularExpressionLarge(expression: String) -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()

        var currentRange = self.startIndex..<self.endIndex
        // use this line in Swift 2.x instead
        var currentRange = self.characters.indices

        while let range = self.rangeOfString(expression, options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: currentRange, locale: nil) {

            result.append(self[range])
            currentRange.startIndex = range.endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by your way now it works but I can't use "." - dot for double
        `let subStringArray = field.text!.stringsMatchingRegularExpression("[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{1,}")
        if(subStringArray.count>0){
            if(subStringArray[0] != ""){
                field.text = subStringArray[0]
            }else{
                field.text = ""
            }
        }else{
            field.text = ""
        }`

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I don't know what you mean by "I can't use "." - dot for double". But the dot (".") in your regrex should be replaced with "\\." since this is the normal string ".". The other one would match any single character. Regrex: "[0-9]{1,}\\.[0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{1,}". An improved regrex which does exactly the same: "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"

Comment: When I run this on iPad Air 2 Simulator and go to this field I can use only numbers 0-9 , but I can't type 36.6 the "." can't be typed on the field. I've tryed with your regex the result is the same can't use the dot...